# Como usar o jboss no eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Eu instalei o jbossTolls no eclipse luna depois baixei o jboss 7.1, configurei certinho em servers, iniciei ele e mandei rodar a pagina jsf nele, mas da 404, alguem sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Olhe o log no console e veja se realmente sua aplicação foi iniciada com sucesso. Deve haver alguma mensagem parecida com *"Application [myappname] deployed sucessfully"*. Verifique também sua aplicação está mapeando corretamente a página que vc está tentando acessar. Erro 404 indica que ou a aplicação não foi iniciada corretamente ou a URL digitada está errada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pela sua descrição pode ser resolvido da seguinte forma. Na configuração da JRE do eclipse, Edite o location da JRE (no eclipse vai em window->preferences na janela de preferences vai em Java->InstalledJREs) Direcione o lacation para a pasta JDK.

[image: edit JRE Eclipse]

Depois de ajustado isso, add seu projeto JSF do server como a imagem abaixo e tente iniciar o Jboss e acessar uma pagina de sua aplicação.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se continuar dando erro 404 poste as configurações do seu projeto como: web.xml, print-screen do eclipse , tudo o que vc conseguir detalhar.

abraço.